# How to get working the code recommenders for javaFX type in the FXML with java11?

Tags: java, fxml, java-11, efxclipse

Since I work with `java11` i can't get the code recommenders for `javaFX` type in my FXML. It's very annoying because I have to write my imports manually.

I've installed `e(fx)clipse` and `jdk11`. I've also set in preference `JavaFX`  the `javaFX 11 + SDK parameter` with `javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib` and create a user library `JavaFX SDK`.

Comment: If you are using FXML, you should do most FXML editing in the visual tool Scenebuilder IMO, not in an IDE like Eclipse.

Comment: I know code completion and automated import generation is available for FXML in IntelliJ Idea ultimate, but I don’t know about other Intellj versions or other IDEs.

Comment: Yes i know for intelliJ but unfortunatly i don't have a choice to use eclipse. My company don't want to pay for somthing they can have free.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `eclipse` versions after 2019-03 (4.11) doesn't accepte the FXML code recommenders annymore. So if anybody else needs this option it works with `eclipse 2019-03 (4.11)`, the last version of `e(fx)clipse` and `jdk 11` or latest.